# Parse JSON in Android

Tags: android, json, parsing

I need help with parsing a JSON string in Android.
I want to get the coordinates of "geoJson1" in this string:

```
{
    "id": "36",
    "place": "restaurant",
    "geoJson1": "{\"type\":\"MultiLineString\",\"coordinates\":[[[5441638.1188548915,6352789.023657421],[5433468.392072764,6353121.617942605]]]}",
    "location": [
        {
            "geoJson": "{\"type\":\"Point\",\"coordinates\":[5433452.050000737,6352982.539981681]}",
            "number": 8691
        },
        {
            "geoJson": "{\"type\":\"Point\",\"coordinates\":[5433379,6354829.689981211]}",
            "number": 3487
        }
    ],
    "long": "",
    "geoJson2": "{\"type\":\"MultiLineString\",\"coordinates\":[[[5433468.392072764,6353121.617942605],[5441638.1188548915,6352789.023657421]]]}"
}
```

What I am trying to do is this, but I am getting a parsing error:

```
             JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(json);
             JSONObject geoJson= jsonObj.getJSONObject("geojson1");
             JSONArray coordinates= (JSONArray) geoJsonVuelta.get("coordinates");
```

Could you help me please? 
Thanks!

Comment: first of all please correct your json string, its not valid

Comment: What is the error?. What is `geoJsonVuelta`??. I guess it should be `geoJson`.

Comment: Have you tried validating the JSON string through http://jsonlint.com/ ?

Comment: This is the JSON (GeoJson) I am receiving from a WebService

Comment: Please provide your full Json String ,you provided only half of it and tell what error you are getting

Comment: I edit the question, this is the complete JSON string that the Webservice returned to me. I couldn't see which is the error

Answer (score 2):

It's tough to tell because you don't say what the error is or where it occurs, and your code is incomplete.

But...

It looks like you are trying to get your geoJson object as an object directly, when in fact in the JSON that you posted (`"geoJson":"{\"type\":\"MultiLineString\",` - truncated), geoJson is a String. Try getting it as a String, and reparsing this as a new JSON object.

`new JSONObject(jsonObj.getString("geojson"));`

Answer (score 0):

You can very easily parse json with use of jackson library. Over there, you just need to create POJO of expected output class and using object mapper, you can get directly entire object, you don't need to worry about parsing line by line, that will be manage by jackson library, you just need to create POJO class with annotation of server tag.

[Here](http://www.journaldev.com/2324/jackson-json-processing-api-in-java-example-tutorial) is sample, which will help you how to use.

[Here](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) is more information about jackson and library available.